# How to create an EditText of dynamic fixed width

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm working on an app where my xml looks a bit like this:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/receiver_name"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</TableRow>
```

What I want, is that no matter what device you have, the `TextView` should take up 1/4th of the width, and the `EditText` should take up 3/4ths of the width.

As it is now, the code works - until you start typing. The `EditText` gets wider and wider as you type more and more into it. How do I make it so that my EditText stays the same width that is assigned to it by the `layout_weight` parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use LinearLayout like that :

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/receiver_name"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:maxLength="30"
    android:maxLines="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

hope that can help you =)

Comment: So Can I stick a linearlayout into one of my TableRows?

Answer (score 1):

Just like Janoub said you could use the LinearLayout and weights value.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html
But you can also use table layout with 4 columns so your edittext catches 3 columns and the textview 1.
http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/07/android-tablelayout-example.html